# Java EE 6 - Why do I need default constructor and how to define optional parameters?

Tags: java

I'm trying to learn Java and I've got everything setup and I'm running. I created a constructor for my first model and went to setup a constructor function that accepts a parameter. I added this function:

```
public Guest(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.signingDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
}
```

Netbeans threw an error saying I needed a default constructor.  The error went away when I changed it to:

```
public Guest() {
}

public Guest(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.signingDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
}
```

I can't imagine that this is how you create optional parameters within Java.  So it brings up 2 questions:

1. Why do I need a default constructor?
2. How do I create optional parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An entity class must have a no-argument public or protected constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Another scenario where you'd need no-arg constrcutors is when you have subclasses.

For example,

```
class Car {

 Engine engine;
 Car(Engine e)
   {
     // do something
   }

 }
```

And you have a subclass,

```
class Benz extends Car
 {
   Benz()
   { 
   }
 }
```

Now you can't instantiate a `Benz` object. The reason is, when a `new Benz()` instantiation is attempeted, the parent constructor is first invoked.

i.e,

```
class Benz extends Car
 {
   Benz()
   {
     super(); //implicitly added 
   }
 }
```

By default, it tries to invoke a no-arg constructor of the super-class. So you'd need one, unless you have an explicit super(arg) call like this:

```
class Benz extends Car
 {
   Benz()
   {
     super(new Engine()); 
   }
 }
```

Note: A simple Java rule to remember
A no-arg constructor is provided by default as long as you don't have another constructor with argument.

i.e

```
 class Car{}
```

is equivalent to

```
class Car{ Car() }
```

But when you write,

```
 class Car{ Car(Engine e){} }
```

there is no  no-arg constructor provided by default. You'll have to explicitly code

```
 class Car{ Car(){} Car(Engine e)}
```

if you needed it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Java supports method / constructor overloading.

You don't "need" the default constructor.  However, NetBeans is being helpful to you, and informing you that you need one because it assumes you are creating a bean - which requires the option to be created without a constructor requiring parameters - because the calling code wouldn't know what to populate into these.

For "optional" parameters, you can define as many constructors as you would need - with each one omitting one or more of the "optional" parameters.

Answer (score 1):

> Why do I need a default constructor?

I think you are trying to call `new Guest()` and have only one constructor in Guest class that is `Guest(String arg)`. And that's why it is showing error that you need to create a constructor with no arguments that is default constructor of a class.

> How do I create optional parameters?

If you want to make a constructor with 0 more arguments you need to use `...` in argument.
Ex:

```
public class Testing {
    public Testing(String... str) {
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Testing testing = new Testing();
        Testing testing1 = new Testing("1");
        Testing testing2 = new Testing("2","1");
    }
}
```

Comment: The original question is a bit vague, so this is not necessarily incorrect - but the proper name for the "..." are actually "varargs".  These require arguments of all of the same type (e.g. Strings, as in the example above) - and the varargs argument must be the last argument accepted by the method.

Comment: Yes it will accept same type of arguments and if you want multiple then you can use `Object...`. May be it works.

Comment: An `Object...` vararg seems like a pretty bad way of implementing optional args. It means you lose all type safety and have to unit test the hell out of your ctor (ditto if it were a normal instance method). An overload (multiple construtors) would be much better.

Comment: What if I want to restrict types.... IE - parameter 1 is an integer, 2 a string, 3 an object, but they're all optional

Comment: @Webnet: You can use `Object...` but as said by 'yshavit' it is pretty bad way to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a POJO (Plain Old Java Object) than you need a default constructor only if you create an instance of this object by invoking no-argument constructor like `Guest g = new Guest()`.
That's pretty obvious - you want to use no-argument constructor - you need to have one.

If you don't specify any constructor, the compiler will generate one (default, no-argument) for you. If you specify at least one constructor by yourself - the compiler won't generate any as it assumes that you know what you're doing.

However, if you're creating a **JPA entity** (so you have `@Entity` at the top of your class) than you need a default constructor as it's a **JPA requirement**.
It's because instances of your class are created by the JPA provider when you fetch them from the database. The JPA provider has to have a way to instantiate your Entity.
If you'd have only parametrized constructor - how the JPA would know what parameters should it pass?

There are no optional parameters in Java like there are in i.e. PHP world where you can define `myMethod($var1, $var2 = null, $var3 = 2);`. In Java world we use [overloaded methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading) and [varargs](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.lang/using-the-varargs-language-feature.html).